# IsKeyboardFocused is always False inside OnRender()

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to make my own custom text editor for my program, which so far does syntax highlighting. It can't even edit text yet.

I've run into a snag when trying to display my caret.

In my `OnRender()` method, I use IsKeyboardFocused to check to see if I have keyboard focus, which if I do, then it goes ahead and draws my cursor.

I have told the keyboard via `Keyboard.Focus(MyCustomTextEditor)` to focus on my control when I click on it with my mouse, and when I intercept it using a `GotKeyboardFocus` event handler, I can verify using debugging messages that the focus was passed successfully.

However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to make `IsKeyboardFocused = True` inside `OnRender()`. I placed `Debug.Print()`'s at the beginning, end, middle, and every other place imaginable inside `OnRender()`, with the results always being False.

My method seems pretty straightforward. I just don't understand what I could have left out. Thanks for your time reading this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `FocusManager.FocusedElement` to figure out what element is focused when you're expecting your control to have focus?  That should give a few clues.

Shot in the dark, is `OnRender()` being called again after control load, or are you only checking on init?  I recall focus issues involving setting focus on a control during the Loaded event, only to have focus revert afterwards.

Comment: I used your idea and figured out what was happening. I was using a `ScrollViewer` as the parent element of `MyCustomTextEditor`. It turns out that my focus kept on routing to my `ScrollViewer`, which I verified using `Keyboard.FocusedElement.ToString()` in my `LostFocus` event handler. This is actually fine for me since my `ScrollViewer` is only used for `MyCustomTextEditor`. Thanks a lot for your help!